# Iterating through a vector, calculating standard deviation of every n number of values in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to write a loop that will iterate through my vector of doubles, and calculate the standard deviation of every group of 5 values. Below is the code I've written to do so, however, when I attempt to run it, it gives the majority of my out NA as a value, which isn't accurate.

data is large matrix with 53412 elements, should be approx 1175 rows.

```
for(i in floor((nrow(data)/5)-5)){sd5[i] <-sd(data[seq((5*i) + 1,(5*i) + 5),6])}
```

I've attempted to itterate through it manually, just executing the following in the console

```
sd(data[seq((5) + 1,(5*i) + 5),6])
sd(data[seq((10) + 1,(10) + 5),6])
sd(data[seq((15) + 1,(15) + 5),6])
```

Each of those operate properly, however, when I attempted to do it with the loop, it results in NA for the majority of my data, including the 2nd and 3rd lines in the code block above.

Here is a few lines from the CSV it is reading

```
2016-04-01,108.779999,110.00,108.199997,109.989998,25626200,109.989998
2016-03-31,109.720001,109.900002,108.879997,108.989998,25685700,108.989998
2016-03-30,108.650002,110.419998,108.599998,109.559998,45159900,109.559998
2016-03-29,104.889999,107.790001,104.879997,107.68,30774100,107.68
2016-03-28,106.00,106.190002,105.059998,105.190002,19303600,105.190002
```

Just in case, I wanted to point out that I am grabbing the correct values from the CSV file, atleast when I manually execute sd(), as I've compared the console output to the CSV file. However, that doesn't mean I'm not iterating incorrectly in a way that I just can't seem to find. I set the loop to round down to avoid any out of bounds errors.

Comment: What's to be done with the remainder values? (`nrow(data) %% 5 !=0`)

Comment: They're unneeded for what I'm doing at the moment. I'm tracking the standard deviation of adj closing price by the business week, for the entire lifetime of a stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a `for` loop.

If the vector is stored as `x`, you could do:

```
NN <- length(x)
x <- x[1:(5*floor(length(x)/5))]
dim(x) <- c(5, length(x)/5)
apply(x, 2, sd)
```

If it's in a `data.frame`, I'd use `data.table` (especially since `sd` is `GForce`-optimized in the [current devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)):

```
library(data.table); setDT(data)
data[ , sd(x), by = .(grp = (0:(length(x) - 1) %/% 5))]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the first solution you posted work with a length that isn't divisible by 5, where I can toss the remainder as it isn't significant.

Comment: The number will also change each day, so every 5 days it will be divisible by 5.

Error in dim(temp1[, 6]) <- c(5, length(temp1[, 6])/5) : 
  dims [product 8900] do not match the length of object [8902]

Comment: @Kristoff see edit. Though this requires making a copy, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can just recast into a 5 column (or row) matrix and get the `FUN` of the rows (or columns)

And since the matrix is so large, you can use the `matrixStats` library

```
mm <- read.csv(header = FALSE, text = "2016-04-01,108.779999,110.00,108.199997,109.989998,25626200,109.989998
2016-03-31,109.720001,109.900002,108.879997,108.989998,25685700,108.989998
                              2016-03-30,108.650002,110.419998,108.599998,109.559998,45159900,109.559998
                              2016-03-29,104.889999,107.790001,104.879997,107.68,30774100,107.68
                              2016-03-28,106.00,106.190002,105.059998,105.190002,19303600,105.190002")

set.seed(1)
mm <- mm[, -1]
mm <- matrix(sample(unlist(mm), 1500 * 55000, TRUE), 1500)
# num [1:1500, 1:55000] 110 109 110 110 110 ...

m2 <- matrix(mm, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
#        [,1]        [,2]        [,3]   [,4]        [,5]
# [1,] 110.42      108.88      109.56 109.56      109.90
# [2,] 108.99      107.68      105.19 107.68      109.72
# [3,] 109.90      110.00 25626200.00 108.88 30774100.00
# [4,] 105.06 25685700.00      105.19 108.88 30774100.00
# [5,] 107.68      109.90      105.19 104.89      107.79
# [6,] 108.88      108.78      108.88 108.99      108.20

system.time({
  sds <- apply(m2, 1, sd)
})

# user  system elapsed 
## a damn long time
# Timing stopped at: 114.028 0.81 115.398 

library('matrixStats')
system.time({
  sds <- rowSds(m2)
})

#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.347   0.051   0.402 

head(sds)
# [1] 5.620328e-01 1.726982e+00 1.555266e+07 1.556640e+07 2.072692e+00 3.141340e-01
```

Comment: `rowSds`, nice. Impressive.